# EXECUTE INTO in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to execute the following:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || row_name || ' INTO row_value FROM user_data.data WHERE id = ' || tid || ';';
```

`row_name`, `row_value` and `tid` are variables of the plpgsql function. My concern is, whether the selected value will be passed to the row_value variable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it yourself! Your function raises

```
ERROR:  EXECUTE of SELECT ... INTO is not implemented
HINT:  You might want to use EXECUTE ... INTO or EXECUTE CREATE TABLE ... AS instead.
```

and all is clear.